# Connect to Microsoft Exchange Server using C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, service-accounts, microsoft-exchange

I have to establish connectivity with Microsoft Exchange Webservice and I have been given the below details -
Shared mailbox address is say -

> "students@student.edu"

Service account is say -

> "Student SA"

Password for service account is say -

> "Pass1234"

I followed the code sample given in website:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications

Below is my code sample using the above details -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
    
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Student SA", "Pass1234");

    service.TraceEnabled = true;
    service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;

    service.AutodiscoverUrl("students@student.edu", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

    // service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.PrincipalName, "myADAccount");    
          
}

private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
{
    // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
    bool result = false;

    Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

    // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
    // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
    // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
    if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

When I run this locally, I am getting below error messages

```
<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="9" Time="2018-06-04 15:10:07Z">  
     Request error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.  
 </Trace>
```

I looked for the same in other threads here [How to connect to Exchange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615632/how-to-connect-to-exchange)

and also on Code project, but they all tell the same way on how to connect to exchange webservice.

I am not sure as to why I am getting the unauthorized access in `Autodiscover` configuration and if I am using the correct code to connect to exchange server using the service account information that has been provided.

Comment: Have you tried [https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/#&&B3mVFkrRTjtVd9gvY/ykStceqaBTOMnoH9T/2wjLLXSMX1WX+ainAdR0WcjAPR8PxXIGjVkJ9bhkQAofvsHJM3HCFvAUY53GHd27OBFJ57b25ezc/qN0ifBJeY6XChv4a2b2RQp+9J2uATaPCaX3ibyBtZrFnyNAvLa0atAJUG4fIkWgxkD3jfDpMIVmO/XzjUzu5A==) to verify AutoDiscover works for the account?

Comment: Did you fix this? If yes, can you please share details on how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Your credential format doesn't look correct you should be either using the downlevel format which would be domain\username or the UPN see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx. I'd suggest you use the UPN as that should always work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the address instead of the Service Account:

```
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("students@student.edu", "Pass1234");
```

Also this basic authentication is going away.
Look into implementing OAuth:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth